# array.splice() removes the content of an entry but not an entry itself

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to remove an entry from an array using array.splice(), using this bit of code:

`let replaceThisArrRemoved = replaceThisArr.splice(positionNumber, 1);`

When I use `replaceThisArr = ["apple", "orange", "pear"]` and `positionNumber = 1`, it will return `replaceThisArr = ["apple", "", pear"]`.

I am trying to get it to return `replaceThisArr = ["apple", "pear"]`

Is there any other way of doing this, or anything wrong with my code that I should fix?

Comment: It is returning `[ 'apple', 'pear' ]`, that is as expected. [codepen](https://codepen.io/kumarmasterpraveen/pen/jOBQMZr?editors=1111)

Comment: Please try this code in the browser console and you will find that @decpk is correct.

Comment: Looking back through, there might be a bug somewhere else in my code actually.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

look at this console output  -

[image]

Comment: Please may you replace the picture of a console log with text?

Comment: I actually use your code available in question.  replaceThisArr = ["apple", "orange", "pear"] ;var replaceThisArrRemoved = replaceThisArr.splice(1, 1); replaceThisArrRemoved; replaceThisArr

Answer (score 0):

I've tested it here and it returns the expected values.

```
[ 'apple', 'pear' ]
```

Double-check if there's a bug elsewhere in your code that you should fix.

Comment: yeah, there was a bug somewhere else. It works now